# Error when trying to run an app with sudo or gksudo

Tags: nautilus, sudo

I'm not sure what happened. A few days ago I installed some updates and now i get an error whenever I try to run `sudo nautilus`. If I run `gksudo nautilus` it hangs for a few seconds then does nothing.

[image]

Anyone else had the same issue, or know how to fix it? A similar thing happens when trying to run `sudo gedit` as well...

attempts to sudo other apps:
[image]

Sudoers as requested:
[image]

`$DISPLAY` and `sudo sudo -V` as requested:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you use `sudo` for other GUI programs? Command-line programs?

Comment: added attempts to sudo something else..

Comment: Share your /etc/sudoers please

Comment: added sudoers..

Comment: Please don't start GUI programs with sudo! Only gksu.

Comment: It looks like `$DISPLAY` is being unset by `sudo`, or not set properly to begin with. Try `echo $DISPLAY` and post what that prints, and `sudo sudo -V` (yes, two `sudo`s) and see which section `DISPLAY` is under (check/remove/preserve).

Comment: Added results of `$DISPLAY` and `sudo sudo -V` as requested.

Comment: Does anyone know what my issues are? Kevin, How do I reset `$DISPLAY`

Comment: A tip, it's probably easier if you paste text instead of graphics for the commands. `sudo sudo -V > /tmp/sudo.txt` and then open `/tmp/sudo.txt`, copy the contents and just add the text to your question :)

Answer (score 3):

OK, unchanged output of sudo sudo  -V shows this:

```
Environment variables to preserve:
    XAUTHORIZATION
    XAUTHORITY
    TZ
    PS2
    PS1
    PATH
    LS_COLORS
    KRB5CCNAME
    HOSTNAME
    HOME
    DISPLAY
    COLORS
```

But your output says to preserve ftp_proxy, http_proxy, and https_proxy (note that all the others are gone).

Note also that your sudoers file says

```
Defaults env_keep="http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"
```

That's not there by default, so either you or someone else with access to the system added it. You could try commenting it out (sudo visudo, then add # in front of that line and save the file). Sudo should work fine after that.

If you're sure you need those variables, you can append (instead of clobbering and overwriting) env_keep by using += instead of =:

```
Defaults env_keep+="http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"
```

Read `man sudoers` for a lot of detail on all this :)

Comment: I put the proxy stuff there myself. (this is my work computer and we are behind a proxy)

*edit by there I dont mean in that file.. I set it up in my .bashrc file and environment variables. should I still comment it out in this file?

Comment: The Defaults line in /etc/sudoers is what keeps it from working. If you want sudo to work but also need those variables, use the last line I suggest with `Defaults env_keep+=`, that should allow you to use your additional variables *and* have sudo working correctly.