# How can I change the default editor of the sudoedit command to be vim?

Tags: text-editor

I'm trying to use `sudoedit`, but it keeps running the `nano` editor. My preferred editor is `vim`. How can I make it the default?

Looking at the man page, `man sudoedit`, I've noticed the following:

```
 EDITOR           Default editor to use in -e (sudoedit) mode if neither SUDO_EDITOR nor VISUAL is set.
 SUDO_EDITOR      Default editor to use in -e (sudoedit) mode.
 VISUAL           Default editor to use in -e (sudoedit) mode if SUDO_EDITOR is not set.
```

So I've set them all to `/usr/bin/vim`, but `sudoedit /etc/hosts` still uses `nano`. Am I missing something?

```
$ EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
$ VISUAL=/usr/bin/vim
$ SUDO_EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim

$ echo $VISUAL
/usr/bin/vim

$ echo $EDITOR 
/usr/bin/vim

$ echo $SUDO_EDITOR 
/usr/bin/vim

$ sudoedit /etc/hosts # This is still using nano
```

Comment: What about `sudo vim`?

Comment: @Cornelius That works, that's my workaround for the problem at the moment.

Comment: @darent `visudo: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied`. What is that?

Comment: You need to run it with sudo "sudo visudo"

Comment: @darent `visudo` is a different program. It's just there to allow you to `edit the sudoers file`. `man visudo`

Comment: @Dan `sudo vim` is insecure. You're giving your vim plugins sudo access.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I wasn't suggesting to use `sudo vim`, I am just asking how can use `vim` with `sudoedit` instead of `nano`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Run `sudo update-alternatives --config editor` and choose for vim. After this, `sudoedit /etc/hosts` should open `/etc/hosts` using `vim`.

Alternatively you can use `sudo vim /etc/hosts`.

Comment: For future readers, keep in mind that `sudo vim /etc/hosts` is not exactly the same as `sudoedit /etc/hosts` even if both commands end up using `vim`. Using `sudoedit` is more secure compared to using `sudo vim`.

Comment: The main purpose of `sudoedit` is to prevent running `sudo vim ...` - which grants you full root access to the machine.

Comment: does the "update-alternatives" method make it staying through reboot?

Comment: this command does not show all installed editors. as i see from an update-alternatives instruction ( https://linuxhint.com/update_alternatives_ubuntu/ ) it is possible to add apps that are not yet listed. i would like you also show how to do that.

Comment: Between `vim.tiny` and `vim.basic`, which should I pick? The option for plain `vim` isn't listed.

Comment: Just to clarify for future readers what it is about `sudo vim` that is insecure, `sudoedit` only gives read and write privileges for the one specific file. `sudo vim`, on the other hand, gives full sudo privilege to anything the user does while in vim. Which includes, through the use of `:!`, running any terminal command, and also anything any malicious plugin might like to do (when was the last time _you_ checked all your plugins to make sure they didn't silently check for `sudo` privileges and then did something scary if they had them?)

Answer (score 21):

Try exporting the variable i.e.:

```
$ SUDO_EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
$ export SUDO_EDITOR
```

A new shell is started when you run the command and if this variable is not exported it will not exist in the new shell.

Comment: Since the question is more related with exporting vs setting an environment variable and alternative way of doing `sudo vim /etc/hosts` is not relevant here, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @BcK The question is not about managing environment variables, it's about changing the default editor of the `sudoedit` command. Using environment variables to do that was something I tried because the manpages mentioned them. Using `update-alternatives` is a much better solution than setting an environment in my opinion as it sets the default editor globally, not just for `sudoedit`. Which is why I accepted the other answer.

Comment: @Dan If you want to set an editor globally that should have been the question in the beginning. `sudoedit` manages this with `SUDO_EDITOR` variable as stated in the manpages and it only alters its own editor preference via this variable. Not everyone wants to use vim for everything, they just want to use different editors for different tasks.

Comment: does this method make it staying through reboot?

Comment: @Dan for me, `update-alternatives` did nothing (probably because there was no default editors config), but this answer solved my issue.