# Lenovo T410 Sleep/Wakeup Issue

Tags: suspend, lenovo, wakeup

I have a problem with my lenovo T410 laptop; whenever it sleeps or opening the led and the laptop is trying to wake up, the laptop just freezes in the login screen, the only way to fix it is to hard reboot the laptop, please help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this issue with "sleep" (I think you mean suspend), I have the same issue with suspend and the led too because it suspends the laptop by default. I didn't fix it, I do not know how but I made sure it never happens again

settings ->  power manager -> on ac -> when laptop lid is closed: do nothing

settings ->  power manager -> Extended-> set monitor sleep mode: standby

I  think that will solve all your problems, well until a real solution pops up. I've read solutions that recommend downgrading the kernel, that's something I'm not willing to try, even if it would work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this workaround deserves to be applied on my laptop, however I'm looking for a more perminant solution for this problem.

Comment: @user274471 would that solve your problem? it solved mine, just tried it http://askubuntu.com/questions/454649/how-can-i-make-sudoedit-use-vim-instead-of-nano

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Fan didn't turn off when sending laptop to sleep, and it would not resume.
`intel ips 0000:00:1f.6: ME failed to update for more than 1s, likely hung`
was spammed into `kern.log`.

Disconnecting the CMOS battery for some minutes fixed the issue. You have to remove the keyboard to access the battery connector. This is with `BIOS 6IET85WW (1.45 ) 02/14/2013` resp. `EC 6IHT43WW-1.18`.

Suspend/resume works again, intel_ips messages are gone too.