# pkexec is stating Authentication failure despite my providing root password (which is same as my user password)

Tags: authentication, ubuntu-mate, pkexec

Because they decided to ditch gksu for some reason, we are forced to only use pkexec. I am currently very new to Ubuntu 18.04 and I am facing this as an issue probably also because of my incompetence.

I followed the suggestion provided by Radu Rădeanu here [How to configure pkexec?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287845/how-to-configure-pkexec/332847#332847) however I am having issues. In my situation, I get the following error

```
Authentication is required to run gedit
Authenticating as: meat258,,, (meat258)
Password:
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Errorrg.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized
This incident has been reported.
```

But I know that my root password is correct. Assuming I am new, any help would be appreciated.

`/etc/lsb-release` in my system lists,

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
```

This is Ubuntu MATE. If you need to know any more info, I would happily provide. Please assume I am a novice user.

The actual command I used was

```
pkexec gedit
```

It's true that gedit isn't installed by default on Ubuntu MATE so I installed it with `sudo apt install gedit`. Besides, it's such a lightweight program and an example used in that other Ask Ubuntu post. It's unfortunate only I got this issue.

I am trying to set up pkexec to work like gksudo would have while opening apps from the menu. It could be just that the info shared by Radu Rădeanu on that previous post was too technical for my little brain.

Comment: For editing root files with gedit, I use to go with `sudo gedit /path/to/file &` - Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/78352/when-to-use-pkexec-vs-gksu-gksudo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use pkexec vs. gksu/gksudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78352/when-to-use-pkexec-vs-gksu-gksudo)

Comment: the exact pkexec command I am using is pkexec gedit. And btw I did install gedit from sudo apt install gedit despite its not automatically installed in Ubuntu Mate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't open Gedit as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414785/cant-open-gedit-as-root)